# How to store passwords in GitKraken

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

I am working with GitKraken on Ubuntu.
It is asking me for credentials for every push request.

Is there any way to skip it?
Is there any way to store the credentials in GitKraken?

Comment: @Yuvrai Patil, did the answer resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential) (Git feature) which will be used automatically by any Git client (like [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/))

Either use the Gnome keyring or the KDE Wallet **on Linux**:

```
Gnome:
    Install:
        Ubuntu:
              sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring-dev
              sudo make --directory=/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring

    Instruct Git to use it:
        git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring/git-credential-gnome-keyring

KDE Wallet:
    Install:
        Arch Linux:
            sudo pacman -S ksshaskpass
        Ubuntu:
            sudo apt-get install ksshaskpass

    Instruct Git to use it:
        git config --global core.askpass /usr/bin/ksshaskpass
```

That will ask for your password on the next first push. And then cache it (encrypted).

You might also need to configure GitKraken to

> Use local SSH agent

You can find that option here:

```
Preferences->Authentication->General
```